# Windows not aligned properly in the preview in Dock on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome-shell, gui, ubuntu-dock, 19.10

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 and everything seems to work perfectly except for this:

[image]

This happens with any application that has more than one window opened. Any solutions?

Comment: I'm not seeing whats not aligned....Sry

Comment: There is no white space on the left side, as opposite to the right side

Comment: edited the photo

Comment: Looks like a bug on the Ubuntu Gnome desktop. File bugs at bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure that's not by design how it's supposed to look?

Comment: @darksky The windows are centered in Ubuntu 18.04, so such a change is probably a bug.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I've reported the bug to ubuntu since it is still happening on Ubuntu 20.04.1: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1886268

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what worked for me:

**First way, not very elegant**

Go to the file `usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/windowPreview.js` and open it.

Inside `class DashToDock_WindowPreviewMenuItem extends PopupMenu.PopupBaseMenuItem` comment the line

```
// We don't want this: it adds spacing on the left of the item.
this.remove_child(this._ornamentLabel);
```

Save the file. Restart the GNOME shell (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, `r`) and VOILÀ.

It seems like the original Dash-to-Dock used a trick to fix items showing with extra space on the left. Somehow, this extra space doesn't exist on Ubuntu Dock and the items touch the left border.

**Proper way**

The one to blame for the misalignement id the *empty* `ubuntu.css` file  inside `usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/` that seems to overwrite the `stylesheet.css` file that contains the specs for the alignment. Just by deleting or renaming it, the issue is solved.

And setting `border:0px;` in the `stylesheet.css` file, inside `#dashtodockContainer.dashtodock #dash`removes the nasty pixel line between the dock and a maximized window.

**Note:**
This works for both 19.10 and 20.04 LTS, that use the same version of the Ubuntu Dock.

Comment: This is just a hacky fix. Another solution woul be to install the dash-to-dock extension itself. Its way better than the vanilla ubuntu dock.

Comment: Added a proper fix to the answer above.

Comment: Bianco: The two extensions are the same :)
I maintain both, and ubuntu one only has limited changes, as the one for ensuring yaru theming works. The main difference is that normally ubuntu version is updated earlier.
Thanks for the digging though, I will look into getting the proper fix in.